# Unexpected output when comparing my input string to certain options

Tags: python

I'm building what will hopefully be an MS-DOS style operating system, but I'm having difficulty with the folders. Whenever I try to create or change directories, I get a message saying

> "Command not found."

I don't know why this is happening and I could really use some help. Here's what I've got:

```
import os

def cmdLvl2():
    print("Use the 'leave' command to shut down the system. Use the 'type' command to start a text editor. You can also type 'clear' to clear the screen. Type 'help -a' for more options.")
    tcmdLvl2 = input("~$: ")
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("leave"):
        quit()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("type"):
        typer()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("clear"):
        os.system('cls')
    if tcmdLvl2 == (""):
        dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("help -a"):
        print("You can use the command 'md' to make a new directory. Use the cd command to access this directory. Additionally, use 'list' to show all sub-folders in your current directory.")
        cmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("md"):
        directoryName = input("Name of directory: ")
        os.mkdir(directoryName)
        if not os.path.exists(directoryName):
            os.mkdir(directoryName)
            dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("cd"):
        changedDIR = input("Directory name: ")
        os.chdir(changedDIR)
        if not os.path.exists(changedDIR):
            print("Directory not found.")
            dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == "list":
        os.system('dir')
    if tcmdLvl2 != ("leave", "type", "clear", "", "help -a", "cr", "cd", "list"):
        print("Command not found.")
    dcmdLvl2()

def dcmdLvl2():
    tcmdLvl2 = input("~$: ")
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("leave"):
        quit()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("type"):
        typer()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("clear"):
        os.system('cls')
    if tcmdLvl2 == (""):
        dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("help"):
        cmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("cr"):
        directoryName = input("Name of directory: ")
        os.mkdir(directoryName)
        if not os.path.exists(directoryName):
            os.mkdir(directoryName)
            dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("cd"):
        changedDIR = input("Directory name: ")
        os.chdir(changedDIR)
        if not os.path.exists(changedDIR):
            print("Directory not found.")
            dcmdLvl2()
    if tcmdLvl2 == ("list"):
        os.system('dir')
    if tcmdLvl2 != ("leave", "type", "clear", "", "help", "help -a", "cr", "cd", "list"):
        print("Command not found.")
    dcmdLvl2()

def typer():
    print("Start typing to get started. Unfortunately, you cannot currently save your files.")
    typerCMD = input("  ")
    dcmdLvl2()

def CMDLine():
    print("Hello, and welcome to your new operating system. Type 'help' to get started.")
    cmd = input("~$: ")
    if cmd == ("help"):
        cmdLvl2()
    if cmd == ("leave"):
        quit()
    if cmd == ("type"):
        typer()
    if cmd == ("clear"):
        os.system('cls')
    if cmd == (""):
        dcmdLvl2()
    if cmd == ("help -a"):
        print("You can use the command 'cr' to make a new directory. Use the sd command to access this directory. Additionally, use 'list' to show all sub-folders in your current directory.")
        cmdLvl2()
    if cmd != ("leave", "type", "clear", "", "help -a"):
        print("Command not found.")
    dcmdLvl2()

def redirect():
    signIn()

def mUserRedirect():
    makeUser()

def PwordSignIn():
    rPword = input("Password: ")
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if rPword == (line):
                CMDLine()
            else:
                print("Incorrect password.")
                signIn()

def signIn():
    rUname = input("Username: ")
    with open('usernames.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if rUname == (line):
                PwordSignIn()
            else:
                print("Username not found.")
                mUserRedirect()

def makeUser():
    nUname = input("New username: ")
    nPword = input("Create a password for the user: ")

    with open('usernames.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(nUname)
    with open('passwords.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(nPword)
    signIn()

print("Create a new user? Warning: This will delete any other users. (Y/N) ")
nUser = input("")
if nUser == ("N"):
    signIn()
if nUser == ("n"):
    signIn()
if nUser == ("Y"):
    makeUser()
if nUser == ("y"):
    makeUser()
```

Also, if anyone can help me with my folder setup, I want it to only create folders inside of the program instead of my base, Windows os. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you check many time for equality like this:

```
tcmdLvl2 == ('somestring')
```

or for inequality like this:

```
tcmdLvl2 != ("leave", "type", "clear", "", "help", "help -a", "cr", "cd", "list"):
```

The first checks for string equality, and it will work, in this case, because the parentheses are superfluous in this case. However, in the second case, you have items (the strings) separated by commas, which to python is the definition of a tuple.

Comparing to a tuple using `==` or `!=` won't do what you want.
Your intention seems to be to check whether the command was *any* of those strings. In that case, use `in` to check whether the command is any of the words inside the `tuple` that you have made by using round braces.

So change that check to:

```
tcmdLvl2 not in ("leave", "type", "clear", "", "help", "help -a", "cr", "cd", "list"):
```